# Calculate percentage-base constraints in Xcode

Tags: ios, constraints

I have just started an iOS project. I really want to add ALL constraints in percentage, not points, to have exactly the same sizes in all iOS devices. 
For example, the point-based constraint between an item leading to superview.leading is 20. 
Since in iPhone Xs Max, the total width is 414 points.

In the constraint section, should I define these values:

```
X.leading 
equal 
superview.leading 

constant: 0
Priority: 1000
Multiplier: 20/414 = 0.0483
```

Is it the right way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use it. percentage-base constraints in Xcode is not intuitive at all.

as for iPhone Xs Max , use `safe area`.

> For apps with custom layouts, supporting iPhone X should also be
>   relatively easy, especially if your app uses Auto Layout and adheres
>   to safe area and margin layout guides.

Read more: https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/iphone-x/

Comment: The problem is, the point-base constrains is not the same for the biggest iPhone (Xs Max) and the smallest one (SE). For example, 50 points in XS max is much smaller than it on iPhone SE

Comment: So what is fixed. for example a label's width is the same for various iPhone. then the    anchor the label . use leading \ center \ stackView, etc.